Can't access first element of array
console.logs shown here
const lines = []
function pdfParse (){

fetch('yerba.html').then(
  response => response.text()
).then(
  htmlString => {
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const doc = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, 'text/html')
    const names = Array.from(doc.querySelectorAll('.x6, .x7'));
    names.map(name => {
      if (name.classList.contains('x6')){
        const newLine = [name.textContent,""]
        lines.push(newLine)
      }
      if (name.classList.contains('x7')){
        const existingLine = lines[lines.length-1];
        existingLine[1] += name.textContent;
        lines[lines.length-1]=existingLine;
      }
    });
  }  
)
console.log(lines) // this is logging an array
console.log (lines[0]) // this is logging undefined

I'm creating an array of arrays by parsing an HTML doc. When I console.log the array, it shows up correctly, as an array of 28 arrays. each sub-array has a length of 2.
But when I try to access the first item in the array, I get undefined. I expect it to return: ["Sam", "You ever tried Yerba Mate?"], which appears to be the first item in the array per the previous console.log.
Am I missing a basic JS concept here? (A note: this is within a React app -- relevant perhaps incase React somehow changes how JS is working.)

Separate from the answer to the main issue in the duplicate, note that lines[lines.length-1]=existingLine; is unnecessary (you have already modified the array existingLine === lines[lines.length-1] in place) and that map shouldn’t be used for side effects (use forEach or a for of loop instead).
